# How do I make wget follow php links that redirect

Tags: php, web, wget

I have read about this problem in countless places, but can't find a working solution (or explaination as to why it won't work) for my specific question.

I have a url with countless links on it. ex: (href="somelink.php", href="somelink2.php", href="somelink3.html")

I am trying to use wget to follow every link and grab every image contained within my site.

```
wget -P /path/to/save -H -r -nc -l2 -A".jpg,.JPG" -erobots=off "http://myurl.com"
```

This works great until it comes around the following:

```
href="out.php?t=1.0.0.1&url=http://myurl.com/path/Dir of File&fc=1&p=100"
```

I cannot make it follow this type of link no matter what options I try. If I type the paths manually it will follow and grab the images correctly but there are hundreds of these links and doing each one manually is not really an option.

```
wget -P /path/to/save -H -r -nc -l2 -A".jpg,.JPG" -erobots=off "http://myurl.com/out.php?t=1.0.0.1&url=http://myurl.com/path/Dir of File&fc=1&p=100"
```

How can I make wget recursively follow such links so I don't have to manually type each url?

Comment: That `url` query parameter should be URL encoded, ie `url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com%2Fpath%2FDir+of+File`

Comment: Is there a way to force wget to add the encoding when its not present? As said the problem only seems to arise on a recursive call. The url can be called directly without the encoding present... is this just a fluke? Rewriting hundreds of docs would be just as time consuming to add the encoding.

Comment: unfortunately, that's the price one pays for not doing it right in the first place. You might be able to work something out with `sed` but that's beyond me

Comment: well although this is not exactly what I wanted to hear, what this makes me think is that there is a way to protect websites from being mirrored with wget, just make sure all images, links, and paths contain unencoded spaces. This would effectively make it so users at large couldn't get past the index page with wget. I wonder if all mirroring tools have this "feature". 

Anyways thanks for the info!